# Which way to go with these bugs

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

Compiling Dart app to js these two errors arise:

Nº1:

```
InvalidStateError: Failed to call 'register' on 'Document' for type 'polymer-element': a type with that name is already registered.
```

Nº2:

```
Breaking on exception: TypeError: Object #<qE> has no method 'vL'
```

The object qE is created by dart2js.
How to find the solution?
There are appropriate tools to find the solution?
Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 2):

I heard N1 occurs when Angular and Polymer is used in the same app. This is a known bug.

related open issues:
- [duplicate polymer-element registration should not break the app](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16158)
- [Get error "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to call 'register' on 'Document' for type 'polymer-element'](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16556)

For the N2 use `pub build --mode=debug` so you get unmangled names and then use one of the available strategies to fix the problem (use of MirrorsUsed, @observable, @reflectable)

Comment: Hi, I only use Polymer.

Comment: Do you register your component in Dart code or only import in HTML?
Or maybe you have duplicate `@CustomTag()` annotation? But I guess then it would also not run in Dartium.

Comment: In class definition (file .dart), before a class dart, write @CustomTag(), in html only the polymer-element definition, name, template tag , etc...

Comment: I didn't encounter this problem myself yet, just read about that others have. I have no idea what could be the cause.